# Why am I running into a segmentation fault on line 18?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, grid-layout

I'm attempting to create a program which employs the use of multiple threads to find how many diagonal sums of the grid created from an input text file match a given number passes to the program.

I compile **proj4.c** and **main.c** like this in order to access the `main` function in **main.c** using the provided **Makefile** in a unix environment:

```makefile
compile:
    gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors proj4.c -g -c -pthread
    gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors main.c -g -c
    gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors main.o proj4.o -g -o proj4.out -pthread

run:
    ./proj4.out in1.txt out1.txt 10 1

clean:
    rm *.out rm *.o
```

I keep getting a segmentation error on line 18 of the following code:

**proj4.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "proj4.h"

// Function to read the grid from the input file
void initializeGrid(grid *g, char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%u", &g->n);

    g->p = (unsigned char **)malloc(g->n * sizeof(unsigned char *));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < g->n; i++) {
        // vvv (line 18) vvv
        g->p[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(g->n * sizeof(unsigned char));
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < g->n; j++) {
            fscanf(file, " %c", &g->p[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

// Define a struct to pass data to the worker function
typedef struct {
    grid *input;
    unsigned long s;
    grid *output;
    int thread_id;
    int total_threads;
} worker_args;

// Worker thread function
void *worker(void *args) {
    worker_args *w_args = (worker_args *)args;
    grid *input = w_args->input;
    unsigned long s = w_args->s;
    grid *output = w_args->output;
    int thread_id = w_args->thread_id;
    int total_threads = w_args->total_threads;

    unsigned int n = input->n;

    // Calculate the range of elements each thread should work on
    unsigned int work_size = (n * (n - 1)) / (2 * total_threads);
    unsigned int start = thread_id * work_size;
    unsigned int end = (thread_id + 1) * work_size;

    if (thread_id == total_threads - 1) {
        end = n * (n - 1) / 2;
    }

    for (unsigned int idx = start; idx < end; idx++) {
        int row, col;

        // Find row value without using sqrt
        row = n - 2;
        while (idx <= (row * (row + 1)) / 2) {
            row--;
        }

        col = idx - (row * (row + 1)) / 2;

        output->p[row][col] = (input->p[row][col] + input->p[col][row + 1]) % s;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Function to find the diagonal sums
void diagonalSums(grid *input, unsigned long s, grid *output, int t) {
    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t *)malloc(t * sizeof(pthread_t));
    worker_args *thread_args = (worker_args *)malloc(t * sizeof(worker_args));

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        thread_args[i].input = input;
        thread_args[i].s = s;
        thread_args[i].output = output;
        thread_args[i].thread_id = i;
        thread_args[i].total_threads = t;

        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)&thread_args[i]) != 0) {
            perror("Error creating thread");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Error joining thread");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    free(threads);
    free(thread_args);
}

// Function to write the grid to the output file
void writeGrid(grid *g, char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "w");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < g->n; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < g->n; j++) {
            fprintf(file, "%c ", g->p[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}

// Function to free the grid
void freeGrid(grid *g) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < g->n; i++) {
        free(g->p[i]);
    }
    free(g->p);
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "proj4.h"

/*
 * Do not modify anything in this file. 
 */

/*
 * Helper function for main. 
 * Check for some errors and print error messages 
 * for command line arguments passed to main.
 * If an error is found, the program terminates.
 */
void errorCheck(int argc, char **argv) {
    bool errorFound = false;
    if (argc != 5) {
        printf("Usage error: ./proj4.out inputFile outputFile s t\n");
       errorFound = true;
    }
    else if (access(argv[1], F_OK) != 0) {
        printf("Error accessing %s in the present working directory\n", argv[1]);
        errorFound = true;
    } else {
        int t = atoi(argv[4]);
        if (t < 1 || 3 < t) {
            printf("Error: t must be between 1 and 3 (inclusive)\n");
            errorFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (errorFound)
        exit(0);
}

/*
 * This program should be compiled to ./proj4.out using the provided
 * Makefile, and it will process five command line arguments.
 *   ./proj.out input.txt output.txt s t
 *      input.txt is the name of a file in the present working directory that 
 *        contains a n-by-n grid of digits (1 through 9),
 *        where n >= 1.
 *      output.txt is the name of a file in the present working directory to save
 *        the output of all of the diagonal sums. If the file does not exist,
 *        then this file will be created in the present working directory.
 *      s is the sum for the diagonal sums.
 *      t is the number of threads (1 <= t <= 3) to use
 *        to compute the diagonal sums. If t is 1, then only the 
 *        main thread will be used. If 2 <= t <= 3, then the main
 *        thread and (t - 1) POSIX thread(s) will be used to compute
 *        the diagonal sums.
 * This program will only time the call to diagonalSums.
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    errorCheck(argc, argv);
    char *inputFile = argv[1];
    char *outputFile = argv[2];
    unsigned long sum = (unsigned long)atol(argv[3]);
    int t = atoi(argv[4]);
    grid g, diagonalSumsOutput;
    initializeGrid(&g, inputFile);

    printf("Computing the diagonal sums equal to %ld in a %d-by-%d grid using %d thread(s).\n",
           sum, g.n, g.n, t);
    struct timeval start, end;    // start and end time
    unsigned long e_usec; // elapsed microseconds
    gettimeofday(&start, 0); // mark the start time
    diagonalSums(&g, sum, &diagonalSumsOutput, t);
    gettimeofday(&end, 0);        // mark the end time
    e_usec = ((end.tv_sec * 1000000) + end.tv_usec) -
             ((start.tv_sec * 1000000) + start.tv_usec);
    printf("Elapsed time for computing the diagonal sums using %d thread(s): %lf seconds.\n",
           t, e_usec / 1000000.0);

    printf("Writing the diagonal sums equal to %ld to the file %s.\n",
           sum, outputFile);
    writeGrid(&diagonalSumsOutput, outputFile);
    freeGrid(&g);
    freeGrid(&diagonalSumsOutput);
    printf("Program is complete. Goodbye!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**proj4.h**:

```
#ifndef PROJ4_H
#define PROJ4_H

/*
 * The struct grid_t contains a pointer p to a 2D array of 
 * unsigned chars with n rows and n columns stored on
 * the heap of this process. Once this is initialized properly,
 * p[i][j] should be a valid unsigned char for all i = 0..(n-1)
 * and j = 0..(n-1).
 * Do not alter this typedef or struct in any way.
 */
typedef struct grid_t {
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned char **p;
} grid;

/*
 * Initialize g based on fileName, where fileName
 * is a name of file in the present working directory
 * that contains a valid n-by-n grid of digits, where each
 * digit in the grid is between 1 and 9 (inclusive).
 * Do not alter this function prototype in any way.
 */
void initializeGrid(grid *g, char *fileName);

/*
 * This function will compute all diagonal sums in input that equal s using
 * t threads, where 1 <= t <= 3, and store all of the resulting
 * diagonal sums in output. Each thread should do
 * roughly (doesn't have to be exactly) (100 / t) percent of the 
 * computations involved in calculating the diagonal sums. 
 * This function should call (or call another one of your functions that calls)
 * pthread_create and pthread_join when 2 <= t <= 3 to create additional POSIX
 * thread(s) to compute all diagonal sums. 
 * Do not alter this function prototype in any way.
 */
void diagonalSums(grid *input, unsigned long s, grid *output, int t);

/*
 * Write the contents of g to fileName in the present
 * working directory. If fileName exists in the present working directory, 
 * then this function should overwrite the contents in fileName.
 * If fileName does not exist in the present working directory,
 * then this function should create a new file named fileName
 * and assign read and write permissions to the owner. 
 * Do not alter this function prototype in any way.
 */
void writeGrid(grid *g, char *fileName);

/*
 * Free up all dynamically allocated memory used by g.
 * This function should be called when the program is finished using g.
 * Do not alter this function prototype in any way.
 */
void freeGrid(grid *g);

/*
 * You may add any additional function prototypes and any additional
 * things you need to complete this project below this comment. 
 * Anything you add to this file should be commented. 
 */
#endif
```

I tried these commands:

```
./proj4.out in5.txt out5.txt 1222 3; diff out5.txt correctOut5.txt | wc -c;
```

I get this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped) diff: out5.txt: No such file or directory
```

I expected roughly this as an output (Time usage will vary):

```
Computing the diagonal sums equal to 1222 in a 3567-by-3567 grid using 3 thread(s).
Elapsed time for computing the diagonal sums using 3 thread(s): 61.737591 seconds.
Writing the diagonal sums equal to 1222 to the file out5.txt.
Program is complete. Goodbye!
```

I need help understanding why the Segmentation fault is occurring and what I can do to fix it.

**Edit:** Since **in5.txt** is extremely large because it is part of a school project, I shall provide **in1.txt** which also results in the same error:

```
56535
82355
15459
69251
61338
```

Comment: And which line is line 18? Can you please [edit] your question to add a comment on that line? And if you used a debugger to catch the crash, also please include the values of all involved variables.

Comment: And please try to create a [mre] to show us instead. Scale down the program you have until the crash disappears, perhaps even start over with an empty `main` function and add ***small*** pieces of code that you build and test one by one, until the crash happens again. Then you can much more easily isolate the problem for your [mre]. For example if the crash happens in the `initializeGrid` function then we really don't need anything else of your code. But an example of the input file might be good to see.

Comment: I also recommend you add checks for what `fscanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). And some kind of input validation to make sure that for example the size you read into `g->n` is valid and in a reasonable range.

Comment: On a different note, in C you [don't have to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858). Or other functions returning `void *`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What should I use instead of malloc to create a double pointer c array as seen in the implementation above?

Comment: @Zodiac - It is the *cast* that is wrong, not the use of malloc. In C (unlike in C++!) a `void*` return is convertible to another pointer type without a cast. (And in C++ you shoudln't use malloc anyway).

Comment: When the crash happens, what is the value of `g->n`? What is the value of `i`? Where is `g->p` pointing, it's not a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: When I created [my own](https://godbolt.org/z/T1q9cda7z) [mre] it at least builds cleanly (except an unrelated warning). And reading the code doesn't give anything. It should work, unless you have bad input for `g->n`, or the first `malloc` call fails (likely because of bad input) and returns a `NULL` pointer. So what is the file containing? What does it look like? And what does `fscanf(file, "%u", &g->n)` *return* (not the value of `g->n`, but the actual `fscanf` function return)?

Comment: What's does the backtrace say from your core file?  You should run it through valgrind, too.

Comment: Btw, prefer passing a variable rather than a type to `sizeof`.  Less duplication.

Comment: You are allocating a ton of memory.  You should check that `malloc()` succeeded.

Comment: It segfaults for me on `output->p[row][col] = (input->p[row][col] + input->p[col][row + 1]) % s;`, btw, which is not line 18

Comment: If the example file you show is correct, then the first line is `56535` which is read into `g->n`. That says you will read `56535 * 56535` characters, i.e. `3196206225` characters. That seems like a ***lot*** (it's around 3 ***giga*** bytes). And probably not correct. I'm guessing you should read `5 * 5` (i.e. `25`) characters. So either you have misunderstood something in the file format, or the file format isn't what is specified.

Answer (score 1):

The sample file you provide is invalid, it should contain the grid size as the  first number, `5` to be consistent with the 5x5 matrix present in the file.

The function `initializeGrid` should test for `fscanf()` and `malloc()` failures and report them with concise error messages to avoid undefined behavior on invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function to read the grid from the input file
// note: argument fileName should be defined as const char *fileName
void initializeGrid(grid *g, char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", fileName, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fscanf(file, "%u", &g->n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read grid size\n");
        fclose(file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (g->n <= 0 || g->n > 10000) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid grid size: %u\n", g->n);
        fclose(file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    g->p = malloc(sizeof(*g->p) * g->n);
    if (g->p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory for grid array\n");
        fclose(file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < g->n; i++) {
        g->p[i] = malloc(sizeof(*g->p[i]) * g->n);
        if (g->p[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory for grid row %u\n", i);
            fclose(file);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < g->n; j++) {
            if (fscanf(file, " %c", &g->p[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Missing data for grid[%u][%u]\n", i, j);
                fclose(file);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Sample file:

```
5
56535
82355
15459
69251
61338
```